# WebView onPageFinished not called when MapView is visible

Tags: android, webview

I have a `MapView` inside a fragment which creates a `WebView` and a loads URL.

The `WebView` loads fine if the `MapView` is hidden (`android:visibility="gone"`). But when it is made visible, the WebView's `onPageStarted()` is called but `onPageFinished()` is never called.

**MapView:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/mapView" />
```

**WebView:**

```
webView = new WebView(getActivity());
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "scraper");
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        System.out.println("page start called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        System.out.println("page finished called");
    }
});

webView.loadUrl("http://denver.craigslist.org/apa/5436947521.html");
```

**Few Observations:**

1. If I leave the MapView hidden, WebView loads fine.
2. Only Log message after `onPageStarted()` - D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:587] detach
3. Nothing in `onReceivedError()` or any other error callbacks.

Comment: basically you have MapView and WebView inside one fragment. Am I correct ?

Comment: Just the `MapView` inside Fragment. Webview is used as `webView = new WebView(getActivity());` So you can say it belongs to the Activity not this particular fragment.

Comment: have you tried my solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this way, it works fine for me.

I have used `MapFragment` instead of `MapView`.

**fragment_location.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**LocationFragment.java**:

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static View view;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private double latitude = 23.0300, longitude = 72.5800;
private  WebView webView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location,null);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }catch (InflateException e) {
    /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
    }

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng mLatLong = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mLatLong, 13));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("MyTitle")
            .snippet("MySnippet")
            .position(mLatLong));

    if(webView!=null){
        webView.requestFocus();
    }
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    webView = new WebView(getActivity());
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "scraper");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            Log.i("WebView", "page start called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
           Log.i("WebView", "page finished called");
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
}
```

}

In my case `onPageStarted` & `onPageFinished` both are getting triggered.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**Edit 1:** Actually `MapView` always take focus while initialization so once `MapView` initialization process done request focus to `WebView`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This did not work. In fact I tried with MapFragment 1st and then moved to MapView. BTW how is this different from the code I posted(apart from replacing MapView with MapFragment). Thanks.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc, Can you please try be changing url to another ?

Comment: @Archie.bpgc, I have edited my answer, please check it. Please check onMapReady method, I am damn sure that it would work.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc, can you please let me know that have you tried solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Android Webview don't support map that's why it's not show.